# Node JS how to update inner-inner elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm working with mongo and nodejs and I'm trying to add a `response` object to a `question` object

Here's the part of the model I'm working with:

```
questions: [
    {
        name: String,
        responses: [
            {
                username: String,
                reply: String
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm trying to "push" a response to the `responses` like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < req.body.response.length && i < survey.questions.length; i++) {
    var response = req.body.response[i];

    if(response.trim() == "") continue;

    // survey.questions[i].responses.push({
    var responseIndex = "questions[" + i + "].responses"; 
    Survey.findByIdAndUpdate(survey._id, {
        "$addToSet" : { responseIndex : {
            username: (req.user ? req.user.username : null),
            reply: response
        } }
    }, function(error, survey) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        console.log(survey);
    });
}
```

However, the problem is that it creates a new question object with no data. Any insight would be appreciated!

EDIT: Here is the entire survey model

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    surveyName: String,
    creator: String,
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    questions: [
        {
            name: String,
            responses: [
                {
                    username: String,
                    reply: String
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Survey', schema);
// exports.Survey = mongoose.model('Survey', schema);
```

Comment: are you using mongoose.js?

Comment: I'm using "mongoose": "^4.4.10" , which is how it's stated in my package.json

Comment: Is `Survey` an instance of `question` model?

Comment: `question` is a element of the survey object model

Comment: uhhmm, I answerd thinking that the `Survey` is an `question` instance. Maybe my code doesn't work, but the general idea is there, you should use the mongoose $push function.

Comment: I've tried your code and it doesn't work unfortunately, sorry for that bit of confusion. I've tried `$push` as well but it ended up pushing the response with no data as a `question`

Comment: Can you share the `Survey` model? If I understood, you shared a piece of `Survey` model, right?

Comment: @danilodeveloper I made the edit

Comment: Cool, take a look at my answer. I updated. (I can't test again :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to add an object inside of array, you should use the [$push](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.push) function, because you have a [subdocument](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) inside your `question` model.
In your case, inner-inner, probably you can do this:

```
Survey.findById(survey._id, function(error, res) {
    for(var i = 0; i < req.body.response.length && i < survey.questions.length; i++) {
        var response = req.body.response[i];
        if(response.trim() == "") continue;
        (res.questions[i]).responses.push(response);
    }
    res.save(function(error, res) {
        //  survey updated with responses.
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Works great! Thanks! :)