# Updating Mongo, but not overwrite current data, just append to it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to add to a list of items in Mongo so if I have

```
items:{item: "apple"}
```

what would I use to add another item in an object instead of changing that initial object? So I can end up with.

```
items: {item: "apple"},{item:"orange"},{item:"blueberry"}
```

Can I use findOneAndUpdate? Or will this over-write the original data. I am having a hard time finding the distinction in the documents.

In closing, what method is used for updating and overwriting and what is used for appending to objects and arrays?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630923/node-js-how-to-update-inner-inner-elements/36632285#36632285) can help you.

Comment: Basically you can add a new "item" using Items.push(item)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator.

For example:

```
db.yourCollection.update( 
  { _id: 1 }, 
  { $addToSet: { items: {item : "orange" } } }
)
```

---

The code abode will add the `item : "orange"` to the `items` list of the document with `id=1`